# Issues taking photo from viewpager fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an app using Xamarin.Android that implements a viewpager / actionbar tabs. When I take a photo using the camera, the app will crash when I tap "save." The following error shows up.

System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find the default constructor on type App3.ViewPagerFragment. Please provide the missing constructor.

This only happens when I use the camera. It will pick an image from gallery just fine. I've placed the code for the ViewPagerFragment and FragmentPagerAdapter along with the call I make to request camera functionality. If anybody knows what the heck I'm doing wrong. Please let me know. I've been bashing my head against the wall for days trying to figure this thing out. Thanks.

UPDATE: I also found the same problem to happen when my app goes landscape. I basically used this sample app and added camera functionality to it. [HelloSwipeViewWithTabs](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ActionBarViewPager/HelloSwipeViewWithTabs)

== ViewPagerFragment ==

```
class ViewPagerFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment {

private Func<LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle, View> _view;

public ViewPagerFragment(Func<LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle, View> view)
{
    _view = view;
}

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return _view(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

== FragmentPagerAdapter ==

```
class FragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter { private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> _fragmentList = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>(); public FragmentPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm) {}

public override int Count
{
    get { return _fragmentList.Count; }
}

public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
{
    return _fragmentList[position];
}

public void AddFragment(ViewPagerFragment fragment)
{
    _fragmentList.Add(fragment);
}

public void AddFragmentView(Func<LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle, View> view)
{
    _fragmentList.Add(new ViewPagerFragment(view));

}
}

public class ViewPageListenerForActionBar : ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener
{
  private ActionBar _bar;
  public ViewPageListenerForActionBar(ActionBar bar)
  {
      _bar = bar;
  }
  public override void OnPageSelected(int position)
  {
      _bar.SetSelectedNavigationItem(position);
  }
}

public static class ViewPagerExtensions
{
  public static ActionBar.Tab GetViewPageTab(this ViewPager viewPager, ActionBar actionBar, string name)
  {
    var tab = actionBar.NewTab();
    tab.SetText(name);
    tab.TabSelected += (o, e) =>
    {
        viewPager.SetCurrentItem(actionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex, false);
    };
    return tab;
  }
}
```

== Camera Intent ==

```
private void TakeAPicture() { Intent pickIntent = new Intent();

    pickIntent.SetType("image/*");
    pickIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

    String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"; // Or get from strings.xml
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
    chooserIntent.PutExtra
    (
      Intent.ExtraInitialIntents,
      new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent }
    );

    StartActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);
}
```

Comment: Did you actually try providing the default constructor?

Comment: Yup. I got a different error. When I place an empty constructor, I get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I think the author of the example knew this which is why he disabled landscape on the HelloSwipeViewWithTabs sample.

Comment: @rdbxinc are you able to resolve this ? I'm facing the same problem.